# When set of bit-patterns, defined per column reach specific condition in large bit-array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization

Imagine we have an "object" which is a large bit-array of n rows and m columns. Each column has its repeating pattern over all table rows. Each pattern has its period which is a number, being power of two always. The goal is to find such row (an index will be sufficient), which has the property of all its cells are true bits (1 or white pixels in the image below).

[image: Bit-Array and patterns]

Moreover, we can "query" and invoke methods of this object in the following ways:

1. Get the current row index
2. Advance current row by x rows
3. Set current row to given index i
4. Get the nearest row, greater than current index, which pattern for given column c will change
5. Query if the current row is solution or not
6. Query column indices which are false (or true) for current row
7. Get period of given column c

All above methods will be guaranteed to invoke in O(1) time complexity. In other words, we know all properties of such object, and have access to quick operations of it, described above. However, these instances of such objects may be quite large (dozens of columns, and billions of rows for example).

QUESTION

What algorithm will be the fastest (fewest iterations / smallest time complexity), to reach the all-true state of row, in given bit-array object? My simple approach was to use method 4. and 6. to find most biggest "jump" possible, then advance (2.) - until the goal is reached. However this may be considered as rather naive approach. Could be a better solutions?

Optionally, what fields of math/computer science takes care of such problem?

EDIT:
Here's additional example of such object (with more complicated pattern):
[image: More complicated pattern]

EDIT 2:
Here's pseusocode of "naive" algorithm, which solves the problem:

```
long index = 0; //long can be switched to more "capable" type, like 
BigInteger
long n = rowCount;

while(index < n)
{
    badColumns = GetColumnsWithFalse(index); //"dark pixel columns"
    if(badColumns.Count == 0)
    { 
        return index; //we on the all "white pixels"
    }
    choosenColumn = GetColumnWithLongestDistanceToTrue(badColumns);
    index += GetDistanceToTrue(choosenColumn);
}
return -1; //maximum is reached, nothing found
```

Comment: How is it possible that query 6 would run in constant time, when its output is clearly O(m)?

Comment: Indeed, I forget to add "for current row" in this point. Thank you. I will edit this.

Comment: Even then, it is hard to see how it can run in constant time when it needs to return up to *m* bits... so already for generating that return value it needs *O(m)* time.

Comment: Right, but in practice m is so small in comparison to n, than we could treat this as very small amount of time. But, yes, I agree with you in terms of complexity correctness.

Comment: Can you provide your algorithm in (pseudo)code? What is its time complexity?

Comment: Is n=2^m a given? Is it a given that the very last row is always the complete opposite of the very first row (periods never start half-way?) If the answer is no, then your example is quite extreme. It would be useful to see a more random example.

Comment: @trincot - i'll try provide code example later in the day. n=2^m it is not always guaranteed. Moreover the patterns are usually more complicated, but in practice not so much. Column may for example has period of 8 and pattern 0101000 "all the time". I'll try give additional example image later.

Comment: Is there a limit to how large the period can be or is it completely arbitrary 2^N number? (I'm trying to think along the lines of saving the time by using the periods)

Comment: @Shamis there is no limit about period, however it is always 2^x, and of course lower than row count of the entire array. There may be some columns with the same period but with different pattern. I'm think the catch here will be use periods and patterns smart somehow (because patterns are known, not random, and periods are known also) - and additionally maybe some kind of dynamic programming may be useful here also.

Comment: Actually as I wrote in my answer, if the largest period < number of rows, you can simply ignore all the rows beyond the completed largest period. Since all the other periods will fit within it, you won't be getting any new information about the issue at hand from then on. If there wasn't a solution until the end of the first period, there won't be any. Period ^^.

Comment: For starters I would try to use/exploit LCM (least common multiple) of the periods for each unset collumn from their change until they all hit the row with set part of period... If I see it right it would collapse to system of linear equations  containing the `LCM` of all periods, and `(index-period_start) mod period > unset_part_of_period` expresions for which you solve the index directly without any further queries .... maybe even without the LCM

Comment: I didn't get `Each column has its repeating pattern over all table rows.` Can you explain the patterns in the image in your post?

Comment: @Spektre you still need to build the equations to solve them, so you have to go over every period at least once - so you are still going to be linear with the largest period - building the set of the equations is an overkill imo.

Answer (score 1):

### An initial attempt

Might be prone to deletion or modification.

This is just a quick note which might serve to clarify some details about your answer. However given the information that you have provided, I will take this shot.

If you invert the bits(and thus search for all false row), your problem becomes:
**Finding zero in a vector of 10^9 * C(billions) of numbers.** These might or might not be random, but if it is just finding a zero in a large vector, computer can do that reasonably fast. Also, if you have only dozens of columns, you should be able to manage with something like uint_128 so the operations should be rather fast. Moreover it is trivially parallelizable if you so choose.

Since you already have the object, is there any reason not to read it as a row of uints? There could be, for example if we were talking not about billions but about something few orders of magnitude bigger. Also, I just tested naive python implementation of finding zero in a 10^9 and it took ~7 minutes.

### Several observations:

Since the periods are all in a form of 2^N (where N may vary from a column to column), you only need to check the rows 0:2^max(N). It covers all the possible options since every smaller period will be already repeated.

It is possible to skip steps with the repeated call of the 4th operation on the column with the largest period and check the respective row every other time. (Once it is definitely true, once it is definitely false. So only check the true cases) It is not that useful to skip based on the other columns, because until you get the whole period you are, unfortunately, looking at random numbers. What's more, after you finish checking the largest period, you have all the information you can get out of your sample so there is no way to remove the need for checking by a clever trick.

If you have a lot of columns with small-ish periods, you can merge them together by logical and and then use the periodicity to re-generate the rest of the column.

### Further research

War for the Log(N).

I will now make several claims:

1. Starting from some arbitrary X we have every period in the shape 2^X present up until some other arbitrary Y. (for example 8, 16, 32, ..., 2 ^ 20)
2. Every period is present exactly once
3. The length of the initial object has 2^Y rows.

If 1. doesn't hold for a given number A, we can simply create a **new column** with period 2^A filled with **ones**.

If 2. doesn't hold, we can merge these rows together by the operation logical **AND** and the result will remain consistent - this should be obvious enough to not require further explanation.
This will only change the complexity of the algorithm C times, where the C is the the biggest such repetition. And C * O(N) is still O(N).

Ad 3: This always holds since if there is more rows then the length of the longest period we can trim the input. Since all the periods are powers of 2 every smaller period is also a period for every longer case(e.g. period of 8 is also a period of 16, 32 etc.). Because of that, if we don't find the solution within the longest period, there is none since from that moment all the numbers will repeat themselves.

**Now for the approach I've chosen.**
Linear solution is the simple bruteforce of inverting bits and searching for zero in a set of random numbers. The next logical step would be either O(N^(0 < i < 1)) or O(log(N)), so can we get there? 
**Yes, we can.** At least in some cases.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import RandomState
rs = RandomState()

def generateColumn(period, length, ratio=0.8):
    upperBound = int(1/(1-ratio))
    repeating = rs.randint(0, upperBound, period)
    repeating = [x for x in map(lambda x: 0 if x == 0 else 1, repeating)]
    result = []
    for i in range(int(length/period)):
        result += repeating
    return result


columns = []
period = 8
times = 20
length = np.power(2, times) * 8
for i in range(times):
    columns.append(generateColumn(period, length, 0.5))
    period *= 2

#initializing the first candidate list
candidateList = []
for i in range(8):
    if columns[0][i] == 1:
        candidateList.append(i)

print(candidateList)
currentPeriod = 8
for i in range(1, times):
    candidateList += [x + currentPeriod for x in candidateList]
    newCandidateList = []
    currentPeriod *= 2
    for c in candidateList:
        if columns[i][c] == 1:
            newCandidateList.append(c)
    print(len(candidateList), len(newCandidateList),len(newCandidateList) / len(candidateList) if len(candidateList) > 0 else None)
    candidateList = newCandidateList


print(len(columns[0]))
```

What exactly are we doing here:

1. First we sort the columns by the period. (In the example I simply generate the periods in order. If your columns are not in order, simply generate a list of indices that will be in order to access them correctly.)
2. We take the column with the smallest period as a candidate list - a list of indices for a possible solution.
3. In each step X, we concatenate this list with a shifted version of itself to generate a candidate list of a length X+1
4. Then we merge this candidate list with the (X+1)th column via logical AND. This gives us a new, reduced, candidate list.
5. We repeat the steps 3, 4 until we process the column with the longest period.
6. If the candidate list is nonempty, we have all our solutions. (Alternatively it is possible to stop in the last step.)

I hope that proof isn't necessary. What about the complexity?
It depends on the average density of ones:

- In every step, we double the period.
- In every step, we remove some candidates, depending on their density 
  (one_count / zero_count).

So if we denote X as the length of the X-th candidate list, we get:
`X + 1 = 2 * x * density` where `0 < density < 1` 
So for `density <= 0.5`, we get our logarithm and for `density > 0.5` we are still linear.

**Note:** It is easier to think of the input as being 2^N and trying to get the result to be linear. However the question asked was with input being N, so we are getting logarithms instead.

**Afterthoughts:**

- In reality, the inputs probably won't be so nice as my model case - the base for the size of the solution is **the length of the shortest period**. If that one is big, you can only get some minor improvements by skipping steps via your 4th operation.
- It is most likely possible to get some small improvement by checking rows as you build the list so that you don't have to re-check. Not sure if it's worth the trouble though.
- If you have some of the columns with a low density, it would be a good starting point since it will enable you to discard a lot of values quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest method is ideal.
This one is based on the sort [counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) method, it will give you all rows in witch all are white.
Don't be fooled by the O(n+k), most algorithms depend as much on the implementation as the math. This one is good for laaarge sets of restricted numbers but depending of how large the matrix is it can require a massive amount of RAM.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

uint8_t height = 7;
uint8_t width = 4;

bool matrix [] = {
    1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1
};

void count_rows(uint16_t * row_count){
    uint16_t i, e;
    for(i=0; i < height; i++){
        for(e=0; e < width; e++){
            if(matrix[(i * width) + e]){
                row_count[i] ++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void print_correct(uint16_t * row_count){
    uint16_t i;
    std::cout << "Rows ";
    for(i=0; i < height; i++){
        if(row_count[i] == width){
            std::cout << i + 1 << ", ";
        }
    }  
    std::cout << "where correct";
}


int main (){
    
    uint16_t * row_count = new uint16_t[height];
    memset(row_count, 0, height * sizeof(row_count[0]));      

    count_rows(row_count);
    print_correct(row_count);

    // prints -> 'Rows 5, 7, where correct'

    delete [] row_count;

    return 0;
}
```